# How to move files in multiple directories into another directory with same sub directoies

Tags: python

I have

```
import shutil

for sub_dir in os.listdir(path + "train"):
    src_files = os.listdir(path+"train/" + sub_dir)
    ...
    for file in src_files[0:split_index]:
        original = path+"train/" + sub_dir+ "/" + file
        distutils.dir_util.mkpath(path + "valid/" + sub_dir)     
        destination = path + "valid/" + sub_dir+"/"
        shutil.move(original, destination)
```

I have two these directory structures:

```
train/abc
train/def
train/ghi

valid/
```

I need to move some portion of files in train/ to valid/ and retain the original directory structure. After the move, valid/ should look the same as train/:

```
valid/abc
valid/def
valid/ghi
```

The above code isn't quite right. How can I modify it to make it right?

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in variables - it helps to find problem.

Comment: What behavior do you see when you execute the code?

Comment: I need to create the sub-directory first before move.

Answer (score 0):

```
distutils.dir_util.mkpath(path + "valid/" + sub_dir)
```

Added this part and it works now.